# How to hide port number in url of wcf service

Tags: wcf, iis

I have changed the port for a wcf service using edit biding in iis. Now the issue is that the url of service contains port number like https://localhost:8080/test.svc

How to hide the port number in service url like:https://localhost/test.svc

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that if service runs on default port i.e. 443 for HTTPS or 80 for HTTP. Change port to 443 and then you can use it as https://localhost/test.svc